# Is the infinite intersection open sets that have same length open?

Tags: general-topology

In the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$, we have infinite open sets $(x_i - \delta, x_i + \delta)$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all positive integers $ i$.
Can I prove that
$
    \bigcap \limits_{ i} (x_i - \delta, x_i + \delta)
$
is open?

I try to show that the infinite intersection is either $\varnothing$ or $(\inf \{x_1, \dots\} - \delta, \inf \{x_1, \dots\} + \delta ) \cap (\sup \{x_1, \dots\} - \delta, \sup \{x_1 \dots\} + \delta)$. Thus it is open.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: This isn't true. Consider sets of length $1$ centered around $x_n = 1 - 1/n$. The intersection will be closed at $0$.

Comment: If $(x_i)$ is an arrangement of rationals in $(-\delta,\delta)$, then the intersection is $\{0\}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you! This counter-example is great!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I think the intersection of these sets is empty. For x < 1/2, you can always find a positive integer N such that $x < x_N - 1/2 < 1/2$. And for $x \geq 1/2,  x \notin (x_1 - 1/2, x_1 + 1/2)$.

Comment: What? It is most definitely not empty, as long as you start with $n = 2$ or something reasonable (anything larger also works) and have $\delta = 1$. Then $x_n \in [1/2, 1)$ for all $n \ge 2$ and clearly the point $1$ is always contained. Also, critically, all points in $[0,1)$ are contained, but any point less than zero is eventually less than $-1/n$ for some $n$ so is excluded. Perhaps you thought I meant starting at $n=1$ or $\delta = 1/2$? If you really want to start at $n=1$, just instead consider $x_n = 1 - 1/(n+1)$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Oh sry,  I thought that $\delta = 1/2$.